# ASP.NET - Razor Get Image from model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have this Model and imageFirst and imageLast will be images from Properties.Resources

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Clinica_Imagine_Web.Models.ClinicCase {

    public class ClinicCase {

        public Bitmap imageFirst { get; set; }
        public Bitmap imageLast { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in the htmlview i have for exemple this

```
@using Clinica_Imagine_Web.Models.ClinicCase
@model ClinicCase

<h2>ClinicCase</h2>

<p>@Model.description</p>
<img src="@Model.imageFirst" />
<img src="@Model.imageLast" />
```

How can I show the image of the model int the htmlview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a bitmaps use byte[] arrays in your model. Than you will be able to use this:

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImageBytes))" />
```

And this is how you convert your bitmap to an array:

```
private static byte[] BitmapToBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, with this method works but there isn't anything simplest?

Comment: @Deinok ideally you have a file in a file system - this would be the easiest way. But since you operate with bitmaps, that's pretty much the only option for your. You can also simplify a little by passing Base64 string in your model instead of converting in Razor or even the whole string from src.